# Get Solution range of NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, iteration

I have a numerical solution and when I solve it with NSolve, and substitue the results in an expression, I get something like:

```
1 + x + x^2 if 0 < x< 10
```

I want to plot the expression above in a Manipulate. Is there any way of getting the range {0, 10} in above dynamically, so I can only expose valid values?

Comment: I don't see how you can get something like `1 + x + x^2 if 0 < x< 10`, since it's not syntactially valid.  Problems with code require the code for diagnosis, or an MWE exhibiting the equivalent behavior.

Comment: When I stared at my results a bit more, I asked myself the same question. :) here is the original problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225485/fixed-rate-mortgage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a [`ConditionalExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html).

```
expr = ConditionalExpression[1 + x + x^2, 0 < x < 10]
```

[image]

To convert the condition to a List

```
(List @@ expr[[-1]])[[{2, 1, 3}]]

(* {x, 0, 10} *)
```

or

```
(List @@ expr[[-1]])[[{1, 3}]]

(* {0, 10} *)
```