# two tier compound interest problem

Tags: equation-solving, finance, iteration

I am trying to make sense of how mortgage repayment figures are calculated for two tier mortgages, where you fix your interest rate for a certain period and after that period, you fall back to the SVR rate.

I use the following as the building block:

```
chargeInterestAndRepay[debt_, interestRate_, repayment_]:= (debt*(1+interestRate))  - repayment
```

and I use:

```
mortgageBalanceOverTime[loan_, annualFixedRate_, fixedLength_, annualSvrRate_, termLength_] := Block[
{
svrLength = termLength - fixedLength,

numberOfFixedMonths = 12* (fixedLength),
numberOfSvrMonths = 12 * svrLength,

monthlySvrRate = annualSvrRate / 12,
monthlyFixedRate = annualFixedRate/12
},

fixedPeriodBalance = NestList[chargeInterestAndRepay[#, monthlyFixedRate, initialPayment]&,loan ,numberOfFixedMonths];
svrPeriodBalance = Drop[NestList[chargeInterestAndRepay[#, monthlySvrRate, followingPayment]&, Last[fixedPeriodBalance] , numberOfSvrMonths], 1];
solns = NSolve[Rationalize[Last[svrPeriodBalance]==0] &&followingPayment> 0 &&followingPayment > initialPayment && initialPayment > 0, { followingPayment, initialPayment}];
Join[fixedPeriodBalance, svrPeriodBalance] /. solns
]
```

instead of giving me actual numerical values, it's giving me polynomials in `initialPayment` of the form:

```
blah blah.... if initialPayment > 1234
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've not defined svrLength, annualSvrRate,annualFixedRate,initialPayment,followingPayment etc.. and some of your local variables are not in the Block.

Comment: sorry about that. should be fine now.

Comment: There are still some missing variables : initialPayment and followingPayment. Also use a Module instead of a Block and add fixedPeriodBalance, svrPeriodBalance, solns to the variable list.

Comment: `followingPayment` and `initialPayment` are the unknowns here that I'm trying to solve for. as an aside, I'd love to know if there is a more idiomatic way of formulating the problem.

Comment: Oh I see - well yes there is [`Annuity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annuity.html) which despite its name can also represent a mortgage

Comment: Endorse the comment on `Annuity`; it's a very powerful function and shows Mathematica at its best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the payments change when the rate changes.  Then using an example of a 100k mortgage on 4% (nominal) for two years, then 6% for three more years.  (Formula derivations shown below.)

Note, if using an [effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) annual rate use `r = (1 + 0.04)^(1/12) - 1`.

```
s = principal
r = periodic rate
n = number of periods
d = periodic payment

s = 100000;
r = 0.04/12;
n = 60;
d = s r (1 + 1/((1 + r)^n - 1))        [Formula 1]
```

> ```
> 1841.65
> ```

Monthly payments for the first two years are 1841.65

Also via `Annuity`

```
Solve[TimeValue[Annuity[pmt, 5, 1/12], EffectiveInterest[0.04, 1/12], 0] == 100000, pmt]
```

> ```
> {{pmt -> 1841.65}}
> ```

Balance in month `x` is

```
b = (d + (1 + r)^x (r s - d))/r        [Formula 2]
```

E.g. final balance after 60 months is zero.

```
b = (d + (1 + r)^60 (r s - d))/r = 0.
```

Balance after two years

```
b = (d + (1 + r)^24 (r s - d))/r
```

> ```
> 62378.17
> ```

Recalculating payments

```
s = b;
r = 0.06/12;
n = 36;
d = s r (1 + 1/((1 + r)^n - 1))
```

> ```
> 1897.66
> ```

Monthly payments for the remaining 3 years are 1897.66

Chaining the calculations together can produce a direct formula for the 2nd payments value.

```
Clear[s, n, x, b]
d1 = s r1 (1 + 1/((1 + r1)^n - 1));
b = (d1 + (1 + r1)^x (r1 s - d1))/r1;
d2 = b r2 (1 + 1/((1 + r2)^(n - x) - 1));
d2 = FullSimplify[d2]
```

> ```
> (((1 + r1)^n - (1 + r1)^x) r2 (1 + r2)^n s)/
> ((-1 + (1 + r1)^n) ((1 + r2)^n - (1 + r2)^x))
> ```

```
s = 100000;
r1 = 0.04/12;
n = 60;
x = 24;
r2 = 0.06/12;

{d1, d2}
```

> ```
> {1841.65, 1897.66}
> ```

***Implementation of OP's function***

A demonstration of how the OP's function could be implemented.

```
mortgageBalanceOverTime[loan_, annualFixedRate_, fixedLength_,
  annualSvrRate_, termLength_] := Module[{},
  s = loan;
  r1 = annualFixedRate/12;
  n = 12 (fixedLength + termLength);
  x = 12 fixedLength;
  r2 = annualSvrRate/12;
  d1 = s r1 (1 + 1/((1 + r1)^n - 1));

  fixedPeriodBalance = Table[(d1 + (1 + r1)^k (r1 s - d1))/r1, {k, 0, x}];
  b = Last[fixedPeriodBalance];
  d2 = b r2 (1 + 1/((1 + r2)^(n - x) - 1));
  svrPeriodBalance = Table[(d2 + (1 + r2)^k (r2 b - d2))/r2, {k, n - x}];
  Join[fixedPeriodBalance, svrPeriodBalance]]
```

Or alternatively, using the OP's subroutine.

```
mortgageBalanceOverTime[loan_, annualFixedRate_, fixedLength_,
  annualSvrRate_, termLength_] := Module[{},
  s = loan;
  r1 = annualFixedRate/12;
  n = 12 (fixedLength + termLength);
  x = 12 fixedLength;
  r2 = annualSvrRate/12;
  d1 = s r1 (1 + 1/((1 + r1)^n - 1));

  fixedPeriodBalance = NestList[chargeInterestAndRepay[#, r1, d1] &, s, x];
  b = Last[fixedPeriodBalance];
  d2 = b r2 (1 + 1/((1 + r2)^(n - x) - 1));
  svrPeriodBalance = Rest@NestList[chargeInterestAndRepay[#, r2, d2] &, b, n - x];
  Join[fixedPeriodBalance, svrPeriodBalance]]
```

This reveals that the main point of difference between these and the OP's original function is the use of formula 1 to obtain the payment amount.

Applying either modified version to the demo input figures.

```
ListPlot[mortgageBalanceOverTime[100000, 0.04, 2, 0.06, 3],
 DataRange -> {0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {"Years"}]
```

[image]

***Formulae used in above calculations***

1. Formula for periodic payment - [loan payment formula](http://financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html)

[image]

Derived from the sum of the discounted payments being equal to the principal.

```
Clear[d]
d = First[d /. FullSimplify@Solve[s == Sum[d/(1 + r)^k, {k, 1, n}], d]]
```

> ```
> r (1 + 1/(-1 + (1 + r)^n)) s
> ```

2. Formula for loan balance - [inhomogeneous difference equation](http://people.math.aau.dk/%7Ecornean/IMM_E12/notes2011a.pdf) (Arne Jensen, Aalborg Uni.)

[image]

```
FullSimplify[RSolve[{q[n + 1] == (1 + r) q[n] - d, q[0] == s}, q[n], n]][[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> q[n] -> (d + (1 + r)^n (-d + r s))/r
> ```

Comment: revisited this recently and thought I'd summarize your solution in a new answer. curious to know if you see if you find it readable.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR version of Chris's solution above:

Using this equation:

```
CompoundInterest[p_, r_, n_]:=CompoundInterest[p,r,n]= q[n + 1] == (1 + r) q[n] - p
```

The [`pmt` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pmt-function-0214da64-9a63-4996-bc20-214433fa6441) can be used to find the monthly payments.

```
(*rate: interest rate for loan*)
(*nper: total number of payments for the loan.*)
(*pv: present value.*)
(*fv: The future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after the last payment is made.*)

Pmt[rate_, nper_, pv_, fv_]:= p /.Solve[
  qn == q[n] /. RSolve[{CompoundInterest[p, r, n], q[0] == q0}, q[n], n],
  p
][[1,1]] /. {n-> nper, r -> rate, qn ->fv, q0 -> pv};
```

Once `pmt` is calculated, we can use it to create a table of the balance after each payment:

```
Balance[pv_,rate_,pmt_,N_]:= RecurrenceTable[{CompoundInterest[pmt,rate, n], q[0]==pv}, q, {n, 0, N}];
```